# Different translation result compare to bing translate

Tags: python, translation, language-translation, microsoft-translator, bing-translator-api

I am finding some differences between the Text Translation API behavior versus online translation on the [bing translation online webpage](https://www.bing.com/translator)

The english text I am translating (to Spanish) is :

`"*Add the shallot, tomatoes, peppers and red pepper flakes and cook, stirring often, until slightly softened and aromatic, about 4 minutes*"`

When I use the Microsoft Text Translation python API, following URL is invoked…

`http://api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/Http.svc/Translate?text=“Add the shallot, tomatoes, peppers and red pepper flakes and cook, stirring often, until slightly softened and aromatic, about 4 minutes”&to=es`

The translated result is —> `“Añadir los copos de cebolleta, tomate, pimiento y pimiento rojo y cocine, revolviendo frecuentemente, hasta que se ablanden un poco y aromático, unos 4 minutos”`

However, with bing translation on the webpage

I get following translated results:

`Añada la chalota, los tomates, los pimientos y las hojuelas de pimiento rojo y cocine, revolviendo a menudo, hasta que se suavicen ligeramente y aromáticos, unos 4 minutos`

Their are quite of few differences that looks very odd. For example, shallot is getting translated as “los copos de cebolleta” via API versus as “chalota” on bing. "tomates" versus "tomate" etc.

Can you see what I may be doing wrong ? or something wrong with the API engine ?

Comment: It's quite normal that different translation engines provide different translations.

Comment: As you can see, [the DeepL translator](https://www.deepl.com/translate) gives yet another version.

Comment: I completely agree that different translation engines will have some differences. However, I want to state couple of points here. (1)I was hoping that bing translate and text api are using the same engine at the back. (2) Even the DeepL translator, Google Translate are all providing very much the same translate as bing. (3) to translate shallot as "Chive Flakes" via text API is quite a difference.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that the Text Translation API is using the Statistical Machine Translation algorithm and the Bing Translation is using the Neural Machine Translation algorithm. They have not yet switched over the Text Translation API to use the Neural algorithm.

You can test out the differences between them here: https://translator.microsoft.com/neural/

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/translation/2016/11/15/microsoft-translator-launching-neural-network-based-translations-for-all-its-speech-languages/